# How to draw in java awt canvas dynamically with only 1 instance and using only one class?

Tags: java, user-interface, canvas, awt

I can't figure out how to manipulate awt canvas dynamically with every form submission at button press by only creating a single instance of canvas and not using external custom canvas class and overloading paint . I want it very simple and within a single class .

I want user to input x coordinate and y coordinate and I will use a circular linked list to draw polygon dynamically .(It's my circular linkedlist project , I have to use it) I've tried many things but can't figure it out yet . Here is my code so far .

Main class :

```java
package com.stabgan.java;

import com.stabgan.java.BCLL;

import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;



public class methods extends Frame{

    BCLL draw = new BCLL();
    Canvas can  = new Canvas();
    Graphics g = getGraphics();

    public void paint(BCLL draw , int x , int y) {
        if(draw.size == 1) {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 3, 3);
        }
        else if(draw.size == 2){

            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 3, 3);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawLine(draw.head.prev.x, draw.head.prev.y, x, y);
        } 
        else {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 3, 3);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawLine(draw.head.prev.x, draw.head.prev.y, x, y);
            g.drawLine(draw.head.x, draw.head.y, x, y);
        }
    }
    public methods() {

        Label title = new Label();
        title.setText("Enter Coordinates");
        title.setBounds(95, 40, 120, 20);
        add(title);
        Button b=new Button("Draw");  
        b.setBounds(120,150,60,20);// setting button position  

        TextField x = new TextField("X");
        TextField y = new TextField("Y");
        x.setBounds(80, 100, 50, 20);
        y.setBounds(170, 100, 50, 20);
        x.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        y.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        add(x);
        add(y);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String s1 = x.getText();
                String s2 = y.getText();
                try {
                int xx = Integer.parseInt(s1);
                int yy = Integer.parseInt(s2);
                draw.append(xx, yy);
                paint(draw , xx , yy);
                can.paint(g);

                }
                catch(Exception lol){

                }

            }
        });


        add(b);
        can.setBounds(0, 300, 300, 400);
        can.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        add(can);
        setSize(300,800);//frame size 300 width and 300 height  
        setLayout(null);//no layout manager  
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new methods();

    }

}
```

Linkedlist class :

```java
package com.stabgan.java;

class BCLL {

  public class Node {
    int x;
    int y;
    Node next = null;
    Node prev = null;

    Node(int a,int b) {
      this.x = a;
      this.y = b;
      this.next = this;
      this.prev = this;
    }
  }
  public int size = 0;
  Node head;

  public void append(int x, int y){
    if(head == null) {
      head = new Node(x,y);
      size += 1;
    }
    else {
      Node last = head.prev;
      Node temp = new Node(x,y);
      last.next = temp;
      temp.next = head;
      head.prev = temp;
      temp.prev = last;
      size += 1;
    }
  }

  public void display() {
    if (head == null){
      System.out.println("Empty list");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("("+Integer.toString(head.x)+ ","+ Integer.toString(head.y)+")");
      if (head.next != null){
        Node print = head.next;
        while(print != head){
          System.out.println("("+Integer.toString(print.x)+ ","+ Integer.toString(print.y)+")");
          print = print.next;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public int size(){
    return this.size;
  }

  public boolean isempty() {
      if (head == null) {
          return true;
      }
      return false;
  }

  public boolean contains(int a, int b){
    Node chk = head;
    if (head == null){
      System.out.println("Empty list");
      return false;
    }
    else {
      if (chk.x == a && chk.y == b){
        return true;
      }
      else {
        chk = chk.next;
        while(chk != head){
          if (chk.x == a && chk.y == b){
              return true;
            }
          chk = chk.next;
          }
        return false;
        }
      }
    }

  public void remove(int a, int b){
    Node chk = head;
    if (head == null){
      System.out.println("Empty list");
    }
    else {
      if (chk.x == a && chk.y == b){
        chk.prev.next = chk.next;
        chk.next.prev = chk.prev;
        return;
      }
      else {
        chk = chk.next;
        while(chk != head){
          if (chk.x == a && chk.y == b){
              chk.prev.next = chk.next;
              chk.next.prev = chk.prev;
              return;
            }
          chk = chk.next;
          }
        System.out.println( Integer.toString(a) +" and "+ Integer.toString(b)+" is not in list");
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Nothing is showing on canvas . Help please

Comment: "I can't figure out how to manipulate awt canvas dynamically with every form submission at button press by only creating a single instance of canvas and not using external custom canvas class and overloading paint .": Ok take a breather

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and edit your question.

Comment: @gpasch I'm a student bro , trying to test java GUI . Always hated java but realised having this skill is a +1 in industry so learning it .

Comment: Forget the linkedlist . Just consider it has append , contains(), remove() , delete() methods . BCLL is the linkedlist class and the last element is also the previous element of the head (if head!=null ) so , I am taking input from user the co ordinates and I want to draw circles around the points in red and lines from the last element in my list to the recent element . If total number of elements are 3 or more , I want to draw a line between the last point and first point to make a closed polygon. In my code logic of drawing is correct , I just can't update the canvas .